# Missing database table in CakePHP, I've followed the conventions and tried everything

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

My app works with other models, but for some reason the "Vote" model cannot connect to the db table when I try to save to it.  I've been at this for a couple days and I feel like I've tried everything!

here is my controller VoteController.php that calls the model (edited down for readability):

```
<?php

class VoteController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array('Track', 'Vote');

    function upvote() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $User = $this->auth();
        if ($User) {
            $track_id = @$this->params['id'];
            $this->Vote->upvote($track_id, $User['User']['id']);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

here is the model vote.php:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Vote extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Vote';

    function upvote($id, $user_id) {
        $VoteObject = array('Vote' => array(
                'u_id' => $user_id,
                't_id' => $id,
                'upvote' => 1,
                'downvote' => 0
                ));
        $this->save($VoteObject);
    }

}

?>
```

And of course, in my database, I have a table "votes" with columns id, u_id, t_id, upvote, and downvote.
After everything executes, I get this error:

Missing Database Table

Error: Table votes for model Vote was not found in datasource default.

I've tried deleting the files in tmp, as well as renaming everything, printing out queries, etc, and I can't seem to get anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *double check* you've deleted all the cached files in `APP/tmp`; and *double check* your `votes` table is in the same database as the one referred to in `$default` in `database.php`

Answer (score 2):

try removing this line

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

and adding this to the class

```
var $useTable = 'votes';
```

It looks like it's trying to use the correct name. so that might not be an issue. Can you verify that your data source is setup correctly.

Comment: The data source is set up correctly because the other models work with the db.  I tried doing that and the same thing happened :\

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the tmp/cache directory.
Fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to CakePhp Conventions, your controller should be pluralized with the word Controller in the end, also make sure you named your controller as VotesController.php

```
 <?php
   class VotesController extends AppController {

}

?>
```

On the Model you are using:

```
 var $name = 'Vote';
```

and you should use:  var $name = 'Votes'; (Plural) and make sure your model name is Vote.php (Singular).

Also you **should** be doing:

```
function upvote($id, $user_id) {
    $VoteObject = array('Vote' => array(
            'u_id' => $user_id,
            't_id' => $id,
            'upvote' => 1,
            'downvote' => 0
            ));
    $this->save($VoteObject);
}
```

inside your Controller not into the model.

Comment: Downvoted, because a) model names are singular and b) it is ok to have the upvote functionality in the model.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. It was my mistake when I typed Votes.php, according to cakephp conventions models should be in the  singular form.  As for the second point, if you read my answer I said should be done in the controller, but thank you for you input. I will edit the post.