# Need Help Debugging CakePHP Connection to MySQL with MAMP, error: missing table in database (for what seems like no reason)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cakephp, mamp

I asked a question earlier:
[Missing database table in CakePHP, I've followed the conventions and tried everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434810/missing-database-table-in-cakephp-ive-followed-the-conventions-and-tried-every)

and have since then discovered my problem is not in my model or controller, but rather somewhere in my connection with MAMP or the MySQL server.  It is important to note that I do have 2 models/controllers working fine with the database.  It's just that now I have added another controller/model and when I try to connect, Cake gives the error:
Missing Database Table

Error: Table votes for model Vote was not found in datasource default.

I have been debugging this for two days, and have reproduced it working on another machine, so I'm sure my model/controller is set up correctly.

I have narrowed the problem down to a couple things:
1. There is something messed up in my Cake configurations that has it using an old schema (I have no idea how that would happen)
2. There is something going wrong with MAMP connecting to the new tables

Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging or solving this issue?  Thank you so much.

Wells

Answer (score 1):

Check that all your tables have the same Engine. I had a problem once because I had some tables on MyISAM and the new ones (generated by MySQL Workbench) on InnoDB

Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up solving this by switching to a local connection and then back to my db connection.  Something must have refreshed.  I have no idea, but it works now.